# Web Component not running using $(document).ready from within the component

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, web-component, custom-element, native-web-component

I am new to Web Components, and am trying to build a reusable component combining a Kendo UI component with a remote data source. The Kendo component relies on using $(document).ready(function() to initialise it. When I put that code in a component, it never fires.

If i just put the html mark up in the component, and put the script to initialise it in the main code, it works fine. If I put the script in the component: I don't think it ever fires. I have put a console.log int he code to see if I see anything, but zilch. I get no errors on the console, and can't see anything useful that can help me work this out. Component code is below

```
customElements.define('location-multi-list2', class AppDrawer extends 
HTMLElement {
connectedCallback() {
this.innerHTML = '<div class="demo-section k-content">
        <h4>Dynamic Stores2</h4>
        <select id="hastores2"></select>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#hastores2").kendoMultiSelect({
                dataTextField: "name",
                dataValueField: "id",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            dataType: "json",
                            url: "https://myDomain/path/storeList",
                        }
                    },
                    schema : {
                    data: "stores.location"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>';
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `<script>` added by using `.innerHTML` will not be run. This is to prevent security risks. For more info you can read the section **Security Considerations** on this page: https://devdocs.io/dom/element/innerhtml

Instead you must create a `<script>` element and fill in with the script:

```js
class AppDrawer extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `<div class="demo-section k-content">
      <h4>Dynamic Stores2</h4>
      <select id="hastores2"></select>
    </div>`;
    
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = `alert('here');
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hastores2").kendoMultiSelect({
          dataTextField: "name",
          dataValueField: "id",
          dataSource: {
            transport: {
              read: {
                dataType: "json",
                url: "https://myDomain/path/storeList",
              }
            },
            schema : {
              data: "stores.location"
            }
          }
        });
      });
`;    
    this.appendChild(script);
  }
}

customElements.define('location-multi-list2', AppDrawer);
```

```html
<location-multi-list2></location-multi-list2>
```

Comment: Spot on: all working: much appreciated and thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if your script is running before including jQuery library. Try to use your `$(document).ready()` function inside, like `window.onload = function(){$(document).ready(){}}` instead of just calling it.